# How to replace "} {" in "{4, 5} {6, 7}" with newline using sed in tcl? I mean "{4,5} and {6, 7}" should come in different lines

Tags: sed, tcl

I've `{4,5} {6,7}` in a text file and I want to get the newline after every flower bracket closes (using sed in tcl script)

I tried

```
exec /bin/sed -i {s/\\} \\{/\n/g} file.txt
```

but it did not work giving the following error:

```
Error: /bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 12: Unmatched \\{
```

From `{4,5} {6,7}` I want:

```
{4,5}
{6,7}
```

using sed in tcl script.

Comment: By default sed uses BRE, and curly brackets don't have any special meaning in it **unless** you escape them with backslashes. So, remove backslashes

Comment: Are you trying to edit some JSON?

Answer (score 1):

This particular transform is perhaps more easily done natively in Tcl. It seems to me to be a good candidate for `string map`:

```
# Read the data from the file; not needed if you already have it in Tcl
set f [open file.txt]
set data [read $f]
close $f

# Do the transform itself
set transformed [string map [list "\} \{" "\}\n\{"] $data]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the `space` with a generic `\s`, and concentrate on what needed to be replaced:

```
exec /bin/sed -i s/}\s*{/\n/g file.txt
```

Please note that I do not have `tcl` or `sed` available now to test.

Answer (score 0):

You use a POSIX BRE engine with `sed` since you are not passing `-E` or `-r` option.

That means that to match literal `{` and `}` you need to use unescaped `{` and `}`. If you escape a `{` in a POSIX BRE pattern, it expects a paired `}` to form a *range*, or *limiting*, quantifier. In common NFA regex engines, `{8}` is a quantifier, but in POSIX BRE, `{8}` matches a literal `{8}` string.

Hence, just use

```
exec /bin/sed -i "s/} {/\n/g" file.txt
```

To match any (white)space use

```
exec /bin/sed -i "s/}[[:space:]]{/\n/g" file.txt
```

Comment: Note that single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl. Use double quotes instead.